# Vim not making font italic when it should?

Tags: vim, fonts, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I use gvim and use the colorscheme called slate. I modified it a bit and saved the changes in `.vim/colors/slate-mine.vim` and all the changes take effect except for one. I wanted to make all comments appear in italics. The comments used to be like this:

```
:hi Comment term=bold ctermfg=11 guifg=grey50
```

but I changed it to

```
:hi Comment term=italic ctermfg=11 guifg=grey50
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried

```
:hi Comment cterm=italic ctermfg=11 guifg=grey50
```

and it still doesn't work. The font I am using is Monospace Regular Font 10 which does also support italics. In my `.vimrc` file is where I tell vim to auto load the slate-mine colorscheme and in my `.vimrc` file there is no

```
set term=
```

command anywhere. Any idea why comments are not in italics for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so for me, I opened up my slate-mine.vim file and did this

```
:hi Comment gui=italic ctermfg=11 guifg=grey50
```

I made gui=italic for comments, and it worked. It made the comments appear in italics. If people find that this is not a good way to do it and if there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: No, that's exactly how you are supposed to do.